# Trouble forming an autocompletion url using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

When I visit this [site](https://www.ktm.com/en-ae/find-a-dealer.html) and write any address, as in `Taekwondo Mattighofen, Am Steinbach, Lochen am See, Austria` in inputbox under `ENTER A LOCATION`, I can see this [autocompletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBLvX.jpg) url in dev tools which has parameters like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULOu2.jpg). The full form of that autocompleted url looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B96aI.jpg), which produces the value of latitude and longitude.

I've found success using the value of latitude and longitude taken manually from that above mentioned api within my following script to produce the end result, though.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.ktm.com/content/websites/ktm-com/middle-east/ae/en/dealer-search/jcr:content/root/responsivegrid_1_col/dealersearch.dealers.json'
params = {
    'latitude': '48.0075483',
    'longitude': '13.1848824',
    'country': '',
    'qualification': '',
    'distance': '50'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    res = s.get(link,params=params)
    print(res.json())
```

> How can I produce such autocompletion url based on any address like `Nachhilfe Mattighofen, Rosengasse, Mattighofen, Austria` using a python script built upon requests?

Comment: The suggestions are from ```GoogleMaps API```.

Comment: Why are you trying to free load off a website that is paying for access to this API? Seems highly unethical and likely illegal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already commented, these suggestions come from GoogleMaps API.

You need to enable billing in your Google Cloud Account, create a project and a key. Then, it is easy to get recommendations, as described [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python):

```
import googlemaps
from datetime import datetime

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='Add Your Key here')

# Geocoding an address
geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA')
```

This is what the website are doing. They have created an API key, they bundled it into the website and they allow their users to get geolocation recommendations. They are getting charged for every query and they are probably protecting their API key, by only allowing requests from their URL.

It isn't a good idea to try to use a third web-site to send geolocation requests. They will also most probably have a WAF and block your IPs.

An open source geocoding service is [Nominatim](https://nominatim.org/). You shouldn't expect the same accuracy and result finding as with Google Maps.